# Describe the sample space using set notation: Flipping a coin until you get two consecutive tosses that are the same

Tags: probability

Describe the sample space of each of the following using set notation
(a)Flipping a coin until you get two consecutive tosses that are the same

If we want the same after two tosses, the only way I can think of writing it in a sample space is: ${\{HH,TT}\}^n$

I know the answer is $E_1=\frac{1}{2}1+\frac{1}{2}(E1+1)$
to get E1=2, whence E=3.

Writing it in the sample space is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Well, the only way to avoid a consecutive match is to alternate, so you have paths of the form $(HT)^nT, (HT)^nHH, (TH)^nH, (TH)^nTT$.

Comment: I put that into the sample space?

Comment: That is the sample space.  The set of those paths.

Comment: "*I know the answer is $E_1=\cdots$*"  The answer to what question?  The answer to the question of describing the sample space?  Or the answer to the *unwritten* question of what the expected number of flips will be to arrive at the result.  Do try to proofread your posts to make sure they make sense.

Comment: As for writing the sample space, use whatever notation you are comfortable with that you have available, so long as the sample space includes each sequence of flips such that the sequence ends at the first time two consecutive tosses that are the same in the sequence.  Written out long form it includes but is not limited to: $\{HH,THH, HTHH, THTHH, HTHTHH, THTHTHH, HTHTHTHH,\dots TT, HTT, THTT, HTHTT, THTHTT, HTHTHTT,\dots\}$.  lulu just offered a way that you could shorthand that using "string concatenation" (*or some equivalent alternative*) so you can use set builder notation.

Comment: Your attempt of $\{HH,TT\}^n$ reads to me as $\{(HH,HH,HH,\dots,HH),(HH,HH,HH,\dots,TT),\dots,(TT,HH,TT,\dots,HH),\dots\}$ consisting of $n$-tuples with each element in the tuple being either HH or TT.